# How to obtain service packs for SQL Server 2008 R2? 

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

Where to find the information about service packs already released or planned for SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Update information, for all versions, all types (Service packs and the monthly cumulative updates) is published at...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that only Cumulative Updates are released for the SQL 2008 R2.
The current SQL Server 2008 SP is SP2, but it does not apply to R2.

R2 is a separate release.

Answer (score 0):

If you go towards the bottom of this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) it is updated with the latest SP/CU for each version of SQL Server as it is released. It doesn't give a link to the KB but it is a good central point to check.

**New**: Microsoft has created an [update center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff803383.aspx) that will show the latest SP/CU currently released with a link. I'm not sure how quickly they will update this though, example being that they don't show SP1 for SQL 2012 on there yet.

Answer (score -2):

I'd try the Internet. Surely this is a simple thing to google?